# How can I record high quality audio with my HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, audio

I would like to record interviews, edit them on a computer and include them in a podcast. There is a 'voice recorder app' built in, but the sound quality is awful, much worse than a dictaphone.

It also records in .amr format, but I want a lossless format (either, flac or wav).
I would also like to record up to an hour, which should be possible as the SD Card is nearly 4GB.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rehearsalassistant](http://urbanstew.org/rehearsalassistant)

Is what I ended up using.  It's ok for now.

Comment: This app hasn't been updated in 2.5yrs (last update was 2010-03 as of 2012-08), and I encountered some crashes under some circumstances (rotate screen, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TapeMachine Recorder (it's a paid app), it can record in high quality audio format.
Here's [the link to market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.samalyse.tapemachine)

Answer (score 0):

Also [tape-a-talk](https://market.android.com/details?id=name.markus.droesser.tapeatalkpro&hl=en) works well and has a [free version](https://market.android.com/details?id=name.markus.droesser.tapeatalk&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

[Dictadroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=SoftEight) full or lite is also a good choice, here's the advertisment text from Google's play store:

> Dictadroid turns your Android phone into a professional, high-quality dictation machine and voice recorder. Use it to record voice dictations, notes, meetings, music, or any other audio and share it via email, MMS, Box, or Dropbox.
>   Dictadroid is very simple to use and has many unique features, including:
>   - Pause/Resume while recording or playing
>   - Insert/Overwrite recording modes
>   - Record/Play in the background or while screen is off
>   - Save audio files in WAV format
>   - Share via email, MMS, Box, and Dropbox
>   - Bulk delete/share operations
>   - Assign new or existing photo to a recording
>   - Use in any orientation (Portrait/Landscape)
>   - Sort recordings by date or title